# How do I see all components in a vue project in a tree structure?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, treeview

I have a large Vue 2 project with multiple nested components some of which gets reused in many locations. Is there a vscode extension that can graphically show what components get used where? I'm currently logging each component in a tree structure mindmap and I'd like to do it automatically.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find something?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I checked out some VS code extensions, but none does what I'd like them to

Answer (score 1):

For VSCODE you can use **MountainVue**, check more details here:

- https://vuejsexamples.com/a-developer-tool-to-traverse-your-vue-component-tree/

And also you can use **Vue.js DevTools** extension in **Chrome** to see the structure of your components, in a tree-ish structure amongst a variety of different things.

For React you can use (in VSCODE) **Sapling** Extension, which it provides a really good Treee Structure for better understanding of your current project layout.

Comment: MountainVue seems to not be available anymore